# DB2 - LISTAGG() with DISTINCT clause - doesn't work?

Tags: duplicates, db2, distinct, listagg

My query has a column with a small number of values in it, and I need to display them in a single field for each grouped result set - e.g. if I had an employee in 3 different departments, I'd want to see something like

```
EMPID          DEPTS                                   SOMENUMBER  SOMEOTHERNUMBER
------         ------                                  ----------- ---------------
0001           ACCOUNTING, CUST SERVICE, CALL CENTER        100           200
```

The problem is when there are multiple duplicate departments for the employee. I see numerous questions on how to figure this out for Oracle and other DMBSs, but nothing specific to DB2. IBM's own documentation at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFMBX/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0058709.html says:
- "If DISTINCT is specified, duplicate string-expression values are eliminated.", and 
- "If DISTINCT is specified for LISTAGG, the sort-key of the ORDER BY specification must match string-expression (SQLSTATE 42822). If string-expression is implicitly cast, the sort-key must explicitly include a corresponding matching cast specification.".

As a simplistic example:

```
with mylist (field1) as 
    ( values 'A','A','B','C','D','A','C'
    )
    select listagg (distinct field1, ', ') 
        within group (order by field1) 
        from mylist;
```

The info on the IBM page suggests that this should return 'A, B, C, D' but instead I get 'A. A. A. B, C. C, D'.

I should be able to get around this by having a subquery do some initial rolling up - e.g.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE, LISTAGG(DEPARTMENT,', '),  
    SUM(SOMENUMBER) SOMENUMBER, SUM(SOMEOTHERNUMBER) SOMEOTHERNUMBER
from (
    SELECT EMPLOYEE, DEPARTMENT, SUM(SOMENUMBER) SOMENUMBER, SUM(SOMEOTHERNUMBER) SOMEOTHERNUMBER
    FROM EMPLOYEES GROUP BY EMPLOYEE, DEPARTMENT)
) GROUP BY EMPLOYEE
```

and in fact I guess that's what I'll do, but the IBM documentation sure suggests the DISTINCT ought to do the trick. What am I missing?

Comment: What's your db2 platform, version and fixpack? It works on 11.1.4.4 correctly. [dbfiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=8269899403e98f64b19e69b6fbd0b98c)

Comment: What Db2 version are you on? I tried your example and it returns the expected result: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=8269899403e98f64b19e69b6fbd0b98c

Comment: Works fine on Db2 for IBM i v7.2

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified, but if you use DB2 9.7 LUW, like me, `LISTAGG(DISTINCT ..` doesn't (yet) work. You have to workaround it by XML functions, e. g.:

```
with mylist (field1) as 
    ( values 'A','A','B','C','D','A','C'
    )
    select XMLCAST(
             XMLQUERY('string-join(distinct-values($x//row), ", ")'
                      PASSING XMLGROUP(field1 ORDER BY field1) AS "x"
           ) AS VARCHAR(200))
        from mylist
```

Comment: Got distracted and forgot about this one - but I retried it just now and I still get the A, A, A, B, C, C, D  result. 

We're running "Command Line Processor for DB2 Client 10.5.11" on a LInux server.

I was able to get around it by doing an interim grouping step.